# Spring data - entity not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, dirty-checking

I have an entity `Customer` and Spring data interface `CustomerRepository` shown below:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Long> {
    Customer findCustomerByName(String name);
}
```

I save `Customer` object in the database and then update one field like this:

```
customerRepository.save(new Customer("John", "Smith"));
Customer john = customerRepository.findCustomerByName("John");
john.setSurname("Barton");
customerRepository.flush();
customerRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I don't understand why it prints: Customer(id=1, name=John, surname=**Smith**).

As far as I know, Hibernate uses `dirty checking` mechanism to update entities in persistent state. So changed surname should be propagated to the database during end of transaction (but it does not - even if I separate this code into two `@Transactional` methods). Am I doing something wrong? Do I really need to `save` object manually after each change? Why surname field is not updated in the database?

Comment: because you never save with barton, or creating 2 objects

Comment: Please note that @Transactional works only on public methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerRepoTest {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    //NOTE: No @Transactional
    public void testSaveFails() throws Exception {
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("John", "Smith"));
        Customer john = customerRepository.findCustomerByName("John");
        john.setSurname("Barton");
        customerRepository.flush();
        customerRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveWorks() throws Exception {
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("John", "Smith"));
        Customer john = customerRepository.findCustomerByName("John");
        john.setSurname("Barton");
        //customerRepository.flush(); Flush is not necessary
        customerRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

To explain:
Hibernate keeps a cache of objects it loaded during a transaction.
When a find method is executed, the id of a newly loaded object is compared to the id of the object in this cache, if found, the cached version is used.

- This is why the version with `@Transactional` works.
- Also, it explains why flush is not necessary - it only forces the values to be written before the transaction ends.

If you miss the `@Transactional` (assuming auto-commit on the underlying transaction, which is most likely the case):

- You save the entity in one transaction
- Reload it with findCustomerByName, but it immediately gets detached
- you modify the detached entity - no save
- you reload the entries in another transaction, and you don't see your update